# "社名（企業名）" となっているセルの値を文字列操作して "社名" という文字列を削除したい

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

会社名を「（東京都）元ダミーデータ」A1:A5列、文字列操作したものをB12からB16まで入力したいです。
通常のコピー＆ペーストは実行できますが、社名を文字列削除してB12からB16まで貼り付ける操作ができません。
`.replace` メソッドを使用している行で、以下のエラーが発生しています。

```
TypeError: COMP.replace is not a function
```

数字等は入力されていないので、テキスト型と数値型などの型違いが起こるはずがないのですが、基本的にこのエラーは数値型のデータを文字列操作しようとして出てくると書かれていました。

どうしてこのようなエラーが起きてしまうのでしょうか？

[image: 会社名元データ]

[image: こんな風にコピー＆ペーストしたい]

[image: 今現在できていること]

```
function COMPANY() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //スプレッドシートをGASで使う宣言
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  let  v = i+11;
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('現在実行した結果出力されるシート'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A' + i).activate();
  let COMP = spreadsheet.getRange('\'（東京都）元ダミーデータ\'!A' + i)
  COMP.copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
 

  let COMP2 = COMP.replace("社名", "");
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('現在実行した結果出力されるシート'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B' + v).activate();
  COMP2.copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  //会社名をB1:B10と、B12:B22まで出力
   } 
}
```

以下が単体でなら実行できる関数です。

```
function COMPANY() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //スプレッドシートをGASで使う宣言
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  let  v = i+11;
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('現在実行した結果出力されるシート'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A' + i).activate();
  let COMP =spreadsheet.getRange('\'（東京都）元ダミーデータ\'!A' + i)
  COMP.copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
 
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('現在実行した結果出力されるシート'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B' + v).activate();
  COMP.copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  //会社名をB1:B10と、B12:B22まで出力
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーが発生しているのは、`Range`オブジェクト(`COMP`)には`replace()`関数が存在しないからでしょう。

1個1個のセルを`Range`オブジェクトのまま`replace`したり`copyTo`するのではなく、`getValue`してstringオブジェクトにしてから`replace`し、それを`setValue`するのが良いでしょう。
あとA列の有効なデータの数だけループした方が良いでしょう。
そして文字列の置換は`社名`だけではなく改行も含めて`社名\r\n`か`社名\n`とかではないですか？
Windows上のCSVファイルから作ると`社名\r\n`になりますが、スクレイピングして取得したデータがどうなっているかは実験して確かめてください。

以下のように出来るはずです。

```
function COMPANY() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let lastRow = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRowIndex();
  let targetBase = 11;
  for(let row = 1; row <= lastRow; row++){
    spreadsheet.getRange('B'+(targetBase+row)).setValue(spreadsheet.getRange('A'+row).getValue().replace("社名\r\n",""));
  }
}
```

Comment: 大変役立つご意見ありがとうございます
getValueメソッドを使用してStringオブジェクトにすることで、文字列の置換や変更、setValueメソッドも有効になるということですね